# Bug in chat? Flagged posts

Tags: support, chat, flags

I've recently saw the flagged posts section in the chat, it told me there were  flagged posts. When I got there, there were only 3.

[image: flags]

Bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that there were 15 flags, not 15 flagged posts, which is a big difference!

Comment: In that case, shouldn't I be able to see how many flags were on each post?

Comment: @Truth It could be shown, but I don't think it is necessary. You can open feature-request

Comment: I mean, that **would** have saved the confusion...

Comment: @Truth And you should know that chat flags are cleared rapidly, due to the very large amount of users with 10K net rep (+all mods), it's not uncommon to see a (cached) `n flags` without any flags at all.